# Why is xcode 4.2 much smaller in size than xcode 3.6.2?

Tags: xcode

xcode 3.6.2 has size of about 4GB but the new xcode 4.2 for snow leopard has only 1.6GB, nearly 2.4GB less.

Does the new xcode 4.2 miss something that xcode 3.6.2 has?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to wikipedia:

> Xcode 4.0 drops support for many older systems, including all PowerPC development as well as SDKs for Mac OS X 10.4 and 10.5, and all iOS SDKs older than 4.3.

The 10.4 and 10.5 SDKs were probably much larger to begin with than the more recent ones due to including PPC and PPC64 binaries.

Answer (score 0):

No, Apple combined many different applications into one window. This makes development easier and there are fewer separate applications, many which contain duplicate structural files. Though some functionality was removed, Xcode 4.2 is till the same basic program with some new features too.

Comment: but 4.2GB and 1.6GB is a very significant difference in size. duplicating the entire xcode 4.2 doesn't get as big as xcode 3.6.2..